# Incorrect implicit region for function that indexes or sorts a list

Tags: plotting, implicit

I'm having trouble creating a region with `ImplicitRegion`. In general, I first limit the region to be within a `Parallelogram`.

```
basis = IdentityMatrix[2];
offset = {0, 0};
unitcell = Parallelogram[offset, basis];
```

I then define a toy function

```
toy1[x_, y_, n_] := Sort[{Exp[x^2 + y^2], Exp[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]}][[n]];
```

Here's a plot of the first sheet of this toy function

```
Plot3D[toy1[x, y, 1], {x, y} ∈ unitcell]
```

[image: The first sheet]

I then define a region that is within `unitcell` and beneath a level set (isocurve) of the toy function

```
val = 2;
region1 = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} ∈ unitcell && toy1[x, y, 1] < val, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[region1]
```

[image: region 1]

which isn't correct because the contours of the toy function are very different

```
ContourPlot[toy1[x, y, 1], {x, y} ∈ unitcell]
```

[image: countour plot 1]

It looks like Mathematica isn't sorting the list in `toy1`. I get what Mathematica gave with another toy function, which is one of the elements in the list of `toy1`

```
toy2[x_, y_] := Exp[(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2];
Plot3D[toy2[x, y], {x, y} ∈ unitcell]
ContourPlot[toy2[x, y], {x, y} ∈ unitcell]
region2 = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} ∈ unitcell && toy2[x, y] <val,{x,y}];
RegionPlot[region2]
```

[image: toy 2 contour]
[image: toy 2 region]

Is there something I can do to get the correct region that is within a parallelogram (`unitcell`) and beneath a level set of `toy1`? I'm running Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: What are you trying to sort in your function - numbers or symbols?

Comment: I'm trying to sort numbers.

Comment: Then there is the problem of defining a function toy1. If we calculate it in symbolic form `Sort[{Exp[x^2 + y^2], Exp[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]}][[1]]`, then we have `E^((-1 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2)`. This branch is used to define `ImplicitRegion`. If we calculate this function in numerical form, then another branch appears, which is mapped to `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use [`RankedMin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RankedMin.html) instead of `Sort`:

```
toy1b[x_, y_, n_] := RankedMin[{Exp[x^2 + y^2], Exp[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]}, n]
Plot3D[toy1b[x, y, 1], {x, y} ∈ unitcell,  Exclusions-> None]
```

[image]

```
region1b = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} ∈ unitcell && toy1b[x, y, 1] < val, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[region1b]
```

[image]

Yet another alternative is to use `{Min, Max}[[n]][...]` instead of `Sort[...][[n]]`:

```
toy1c[x_, y_,  n_] := {Min, Max}[[n]][{Exp[x^2 + y^2], Exp[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]}] 
region1c = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} ∈  unitcell && toy1c[x, y, 1] < val, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[region1c]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function without using `Sort`.

```
toy1[x_, y_, n_] := 
 Sort[{Exp[x^2 + y^2], Exp[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]}][[n]]

toy2[x_, y_] := 
 If[Exp[x^2 + y^2] < Exp[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2], Exp[x^2 + y^2], 
  Exp[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]]
basis = IdentityMatrix[2];
offset = {0, 0};
unitcell = Parallelogram[offset, basis];
val = 2;
region1 = 
  ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] unitcell && toy2[x, y] <= val, {x, 
    y}];
RegionPlot[region1]
```

[image: fig1]